# How do I reinitialize session state for a MVC/WEB.API application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is is possible to re-initialize session state after using `Session.Abandon();`?  Meaning, re-trigger `Session_Start` in the global.asax file.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a value to session `Session["aKey"]=something`

Note: It is not a good idea to use Session in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: last resort situation

Answer (score 0):

According [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx), `Abandon` method simply destroys old object, and creates a new one, so you can use the new one.

> A new [`Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.start.aspx) event will be raised on the next request.

So you can [`Redirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) your user to some other page, and the session will be started again from blank.

An important thing is that `Session` identifiers for abandoned or expired sessions are recycled by default. That is, if a request is made that includes the session identifier for an expired or abandoned session, **a new session is started using the same session identifier**. You can disable this by setting `regenerateExpiredSessionId` attribute of the `sessionState` configuration element to `true`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but stepping through it never hits global.asax.

Comment: @JohnSchultz `Start` event will be raised only on a new `request` to your server. So you can `Redirect` your user to some other page, and the session will be started again from blank

Comment: Tried redirecting to a different page using `return View("");`, unfortunately, instead of atleast 4 keys, its only populating 1 and that is not supposed to be there. What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnSchultz Did you fall into `Start` event? What method for the `Redirect` did you use?

Comment: @JohnSchultz Can you provide some code to reproduce th bug?

Comment: user logs in for first time and the correct session state values exist, User then logs out, `issue return view("");` to different view and login view is generated. User (any user) logs in and the session state is still clear. I am using `session.abandon` to clear the session state.

Comment: as far as a code sample, how do I do that in comments with limited # of chars?

Comment: I think I have a temporary work around. by doing a `response.redirect` before the return view the session state re-initializes. I know this is prob not the cleanest way to do it, but for now its working. I just do not understand why the session state is not reinitalizing.

Comment: @JohnSchultz Why use `Abandon` for such task? Why don't you use the `Clear` method?

Comment: I get the same results